# Django Templates Development vs. Production

Tags: python, django

I'm inheriting a product from someone who used Django and I have absolutely no idea how to use it.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to serve up different `scripts` in my `base.html` file, something like this:

```
<!-- if development -->
<script src="{% static "js/main.js" %}></script>
<! -- end -->

<!-- if production -->
<script src="{% static "production/js/main.min.js" %}></script>
<! -- end -->
```

The file structure is as follows:

```
app_name
|__ pages
|__ settings
|__ static
|__ templates
|__ etc
```

Inside the `settings` folder, there looks to be 3 files:

```
base.py : shared settings
development.py
production.py
```

Inside `development.py`,

```
from app_name.settings.base import *

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

// etc
```

I tried to do something like the following inside `templates/base.html`, but obviously not that easy.

```
{% if DEBUG %}
STUFF
{% endif %}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to send your DEBUG in the settings to the templates.

The correct way to do that is to use [context_processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS), which populate the context of the template rendering with variables.

For your particular example, one way to solve it is to define a new module `context_processors.py` in your app_name, and write on it

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve
from settings import DEBUG

def debug_settings(request):
    return {'DEBUG': DEBUG}
```

and in settings.py, use

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ("django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                               "django.core.context_processors.debug",
                               "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
                               "django.core.context_processors.media",
                               "django.core.context_processors.static",
                               "django.core.context_processors.tz",
                               "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
                               "django.core.context_processors.request",
                               "app_name.context_processors.debug_settings",)
```

This will make all templates to see your `DEBUG` settings.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Where do I save the `context_processors.py` file?

Comment: inside your app, anywhere. You only have to pinpoint it in the TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS. EDIT: I added that to the answer.

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel. django.core.context_processors.debug already does it for you if used properly.

Comment: @cusejuice, I believe isobolev is correct. There is already a debug context processor just for that (that I was not aware of). His answer - arguably presented in a more didactic way - is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make use of built in [debug context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-debug). And don't forget to set INTERNAL_IPS setting (to ('127.0.0.1', ) for instance).
After that:

```
{% if debug %}
STUFF
{% endif %}
```

should work.